# Advisor not responding to emails, conference fee deadline approaching

Tags: advisor, conference, communication, fees, government-institutes

**TL;DR::** My advisor, who is in charge of paying a conference paper registration fee, is nonresponsive and the deadline is approaching. What can I do?

I am working part-time in a research institute, which is running mostly from home-office right now.
Together with a professor and my institute supervisor we wrote a conference paper that was accepted in peer review, and the next deadline for the final submission is drawing close.

My advisor is the one responsible for the funding, and I talked to him (voice chat) about paying the registration fee. Afterwards, I have emailed him about other issues as well, for example me needing to get permission to enter the institute for paper-related things (need to update a plot etc.). I have not heard from him since around 3 weeks. He may very well be on vacation, but has not set up an away-message. He may or may not have forgotten about the deadline.

**Question:** How can I handle the registration fee deadline, without knowing whether my advisor will take care of it in time?

I see some options here:

- Wait and do nothing about it, the problem might resolve itself
- Escalate the problem and email either the professor, a higher-up or a different institute advisor who may know which steps to take
- Pay the fee myself and hope it will be covered by the institute later

Note that in theory I could afford to temporarily cover the fee, but generally I would like to avoid it.

---

This question may very well be overly cautious but raising money from the institute may take some time.

I am aware of [this related question about withdrawal due to funding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77884/withdrawing-conference-paper-after-acceptance-due-to-budget-issue), but I do not want to withdraw the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many conference organizers are well aware of how "organized" some advisors / faculty / university accounting departments are.

Contact them and if you can provide evidence that it will "eventually" be paid then they will usually accept that.